# Who's the actress in this sci-fi comedy film/TV series (Name of film/TV series unknown)

Tags: story-identification

What's the name of the actress in this clip:

Once I know the name of the actress I can look her up on IMDB and work out what the film or TV series is called

Comment: The filming location is [Mister Ed's Elephant Museum in Gettysburg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQbEV.png). From there it's just a question of googling and adding the word "movie", the scanning through film trailers.

Comment: I don't go by landmarks or place names. Unless it's a landmark that's know worldwide any place names in a film or TV series might be either made or or changed from the real place name

Comment: I didn't know the place until I googled it. The point I was trying to make is that you can sometimes get extra detail for a story-ID by looking at background details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [Beth Behrs](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm3396631/?ref_=tt_cl_t3) as 'Aliengirl'. The clip is from the comedy film [Route 30, too](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1839597/)

Comment: Looking it up on Amazon, it looks like it was only ever released in the US as Amazon UK only has it available as a US import (NTSC). :(